# Android: DO WHILE AsyncTasks with OkHttpClient

Tags: java, android, sql, android-asynctask, okhttp

I have an `AsyncTask` that sends data to a server. There is 1 call for each record in an SQL database. Once the HTTP call is competed, that record is marked as "uploaded". And I need to do this for all records that are not marked as "uploaded".

```
public void sync (final Context context, final boolean manualSync, final boolean rosterOnly, final String type) {

    if ( unsentScansObjects == null ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "sync: Loading Unsent Scans from Database...");
        unsentScansObjects = unsentScans();
    }

    if ( unsentScansObjects.size() != 0 ) {

        isUploading = true;

        final ScanModel model = (ScanModel) unsentScansObjects.get(0);

        UploadTask upload = (UploadTask) new UploadTask(mContext);
        upload.completionBlock = new PPCompletionBlock() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(Boolean success, JSONObject object, String error) {

                // Scan was marked as "uploaded", remove it from the array
                unsentScansObjects.remove(model);

                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // Keep calling sync until unsentScansObjects.size() == 0
                        sync(context, manualSync, rosterOnly, type);
                    }
                },500);
            }
        };
        upload.execute(model);
    }
    else {
        isUploading = false;
        unsentScansObjects = null;
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to upload all scans until there are none left?

I have tried a **do { upload(); } while (unsentScansObjects.size() != 0);**, but I need to wait until each http call and scan marked as "uploaded" is completed before moving on to the next.

### I will note that this method works very well, but it was requested by client to have this as an "EOF", 1 call (not looping) type of function.

Comment: Is it a requirement that they upload sequentially? Either way, I would probably create a job and use RxJava to carry out the operation(s).

Comment: @Vesper not required to upload sequentially, no.